# Remove 'product' & 'product-cateogory' from url - woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm using WooCommerce for a shopping site and it is adding slug or base to the urls. For instance:
http://dev.unwaveringmedia.com/8dim/product-category/all-party-supplies/
http://dev.unwaveringmedia.com/8dim/product/14-snowman-serving-tray/

I don't want slug/base (product & product-category) in urls.

Is there any way or plugins to remove them from urls?

Comment: I'm looking for the same answer.  The problem is "product-category" is the default setting.  I did a grep through all the files for "product-category" and still can't figure it out.  There's no "product-category" in .htaccess either.  IMO, this is a Wordpress question, as the plugin depends on WordPress permalink settings. And it's not like Woocommerce is an obscure plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this neat little article on it, try this out!

http://ryansechrest.com/2013/04/remove-post-type-slug-in-custom-post-type-url-and-move-subpages-to-website-root-in-wordpress/

It's a guide/tutorial, so you should be able to get more information on what's going on here if you visit his site.

***By the way***, it's against the rules to ask for a plugin here.

```
add_action(
  'pre_get_posts',
  'custom_pre_get_posts'
);

function custom_pre_get_posts($query) {
    global $wpdb;

    if(!$query->is_main_query()) {
      return;
    }

    $post_name = $query->get('pagename');

    $post_type = $wpdb->get_var(
      $wpdb->prepare(
        'SELECT post_type FROM ' . $wpdb->posts . ' WHERE post_name = %s LIMIT 1',
        $post_name
      )
    );

    switch($post_type) {
      case 'services':
        $query->set('services', $post_name);
        $query->set('post_type', $post_type);
        $query->is_single = true;
        $query->is_page = false;
        break;
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Great, I'm glad I could help.  It's amazing what Google can turn up if you find the right query.